# All JFrame freeze while do JavaMail

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jakarta-mail, event-dispatch-thread

I develop program of car management system. Then I want to send mail to owner of this company when car coming in and car out. 
 My code can send mail successfully but I notice that while mail send, other JFrame window is freeze (I can't do anything on all JFrame window) until mail send is complete.
 Is this normally for Javamail or there is a way to make other JFrame still working?

In my program, it take about 10 seconds to complete send one mail.

Comment: you have to use another thread

Comment: Do you need to send just one e-mail or many? If you need to send a number of e-mails, you should probably display some progress bar or the results of the e-mails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do heavy task you should run them in  another threads rather in the same as gui.  If you run in [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) then the gui is gonna freeze until finish.

You can use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) here is an example i really like [Swing Worker Example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

Example:

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
       //here you send the mail
       return "DONE";
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        super.done();
        //this is executed in the EDT
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Message sent", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank! I read your code also with link that you provide and it work.